# Reproduce plots with confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
Group     Ratio1    Ratio2  Amount  CI-High CI-Low
Group 1    0.93     0.85    100     1.13    0.73
Group 2    0.67     1.2     200     0.87    0.47
```

I would like to plot this data and its confidence interval following the sample chart below. How can I use ggplot to do it? (I only need one bar here and any color is fine)

[image]

Comment: You are not very explicit as to which columns corresponds to which elements of the plot. Are e.g. the points and whiskers the ratios or the amounts? And if the ratios, do the two ratios have the same CI intervals? What is the transformation between the two y-axes? 
Try drawing the correct plot by hand (on paper if necessary) with the data you have displayed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?